# Allow user to run script on website

Tags: javascript, html

One of our customer has asked us if we can optionally allow them to run javascript on our website for the live video. We have a control panel where our customers can control their sensors.

**They asked "Is it possible for adding embedded code as an option for adding live video as this give us options to control how the axis camera image is displayed.
e.g. from the Axis Camera HTML setup examples we have:"**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
// Set the BaseURL to the URL of your camera
var BaseURL = "http://r2.mike.com/";
// DisplayWidth & DisplayHeight specifies the displayed width &
height of the image.
// You may change these numbers, the effect will be a stretched or a
shrunk image
var DisplayWidth = "352";
var DisplayHeight = "288";
// This is the path to the image generating file inside the camera
itself
var File = "axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=CIF";
// No changes required below this point
var output = "";
if ((navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
&&
   (navigator.platform != "MacPPC") &&
(navigator.platform != "Mac68k"))
{
  // If Internet Explorer under Windows then use ActiveX 
  output  = '<OBJECT ID="Player" width='
  output += DisplayWidth;
  output += ' height=';
  output += DisplayHeight;
  output += '
CLASSID="CLSID:DE625294-70E6-45ED-B895-CFFA13AEB044" ';
  output += 'CODEBASE="';
  output += BaseURL;
  output += 'activex/AMC.cab#version=5,6,2,4">';
  output += '<PARAM NAME="MediaURL" VALUE="';
  output += BaseURL;
  output += File + '">';
  output += '<param name="MediaType"
value="mjpeg">';
  output += '<param name="ShowStatusBar"
value="0">';
  output += '<param name="ShowToolbar"
value="0">';
  output += '<param name="AutoStart"
value="1">';
  output += '<param name="StretchToFit"
value="1">';
  // Remove the // for the ptz settings below to use the code for
click-in-image. 
     //  output += '<param
name="PTZControlURL" value="';
     //  output += BaseURL;
     //  output +=
'/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?camera=1">';
     //  output += '<param
name="UIMode" value="ptz-relative">'; // or
"ptz-absolute"
  output += '<BR><B>Axis Media
Control</B><BR>';
  output += 'The AXIS Media Control, which enables you ';
  output += 'to view live image streams in Microsoft Internet';
  output += ' Explorer, could not be registered on your computer.';
  output += '<BR></OBJECT>';
} else {
  // If not IE for Windows use the browser itself to display
  theDate = new Date();
  output  = '<IMG SRC="';
  output += BaseURL;
  output += File;
  output += '&dummy=' + theDate.getTime().toString(10);
  output += '" HEIGHT="';
  output += DisplayHeight;
  output += '" WIDTH="';
  output += DisplayWidth;
  output += '" ALT="Camera Image">';
}
document.write(output);
document.Player.ToolbarConfiguration =
"play,+snapshot,+fullscreen"

// Remove the // below to use the code for Motion Detection. 
  // document.Player.UIMode = "MDConfig";
  // document.Player.MotionConfigURL =
"/axis-cgi/operator/param.cgi?ImageSource=0"
  // document.Player.MotionDataURL =
"/axis-cgi/motion/motiondata.cgi";
</SCRIPT>
```

Is there a secure way to allow users to run javascript on the website?

Thanks

Comment: Its not secure, I don't think there is a way to make it secure.

Comment: There is one way, the HTML5's sandbox attribute for iframe. That gives you the ability to control access to main frame etc. This post has some facts about sandboxing an iframe: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/?redirect_from_locale=fa